# Blazor component on page is reloading on page show/hide actions

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am building a Blazor 6.0 server-side project, and came across some unexpected behavior.

The Blazor page has a button that toggles a variable that controls whether or not a component is shown:

```
<input type="button" @onclick="ShowComponent" value="ShowHide" />
....
@if (showComponent) 
   {
      <MyComponent></MyComponent>
   }
```

Variable *showComponent* is initially set to true, so the markup in `<MyComponent>` displays when the page loads. Clicking the page button shows and hides `<MyComponent>` correctly.

However, `<MyComponent>` reloads when it is redisplayed! I confirmed that the `OnAfterRenderAsync` method is called when the component is to be displayed again. That method also has the *firstRender* parameter set to true on the redisplay, which means that my load data calls in that method are executed again. Also, all component level variables are reset.

I do not want nor understand this behavior. I am not leaving the page, I'm simply showing and hiding a component. Why is the component completely being reloaded/refreshed every time? More importantly, how can I prevent this without resorting to JavaScript? Thanks, BB.

Note: I should add that I am not using an `<EditForm>` element in my Razor page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're experiencing unexpected behavior with the reloading and re-rendering of your Blazor component when toggling its visibility. This behavior might be related to the component's lifecycle and the way Blazor handles rendering. Let's try to troubleshoot and find a solution for your issue.

Component Reloading on Toggle:
The behavior you're seeing might be due to the component's lifecycle and Blazor's rendering mechanism. Even though you're toggling the visibility of the component, it's still being re-rendered as part of Blazor's rendering process. This is why the OnAfterRenderAsync method is being called and why you're observing a re-initialization of component-level variables.

Preventing Component Reload:
If you want to prevent the component from reloading and re-rendering when toggling its visibility, you might need to manage the visibility differently. One way to achieve this is by using CSS to control the display of the component rather than removing it from the DOM. You can use a CSS class to toggle the visibility:

```
`<input type="button" @onclick="ToggleComponent" value="ShowHide" />
<div class="@ (showComponent ? "visible" : "hidden")">
<MyComponent></MyComponent>
</div>`
```

Then, define the visible and hidden classes in your CSS to control the display property.

```
.visible {
 display: block;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

This way, the component remains in the DOM but is just hidden or shown based on the CSS class.

Component State Persistence:
If you want to maintain the state of the component even after it's hidden and shown again, you could consider using a state management solution like StateHasChanged method or CascadingValue. This way, the component's state will be retained even when it's re-rendered.

Check for Side Effects in OnAfterRenderAsync:
Make sure that the code within your OnAfterRenderAsync method isn't causing any unwanted side effects when the component is re-rendered. If you have data loading or other operations there, they might be contributing to the behavior you're observing.

Remember, Blazor's rendering and component lifecycle are designed to optimize performance. If a component is re-rendered, it's typically because something has changed, even if it's just a change in visibility. Using CSS to manage visibility and considering state management solutions can help you achieve the behavior you're looking for without excessive reloading.

Comment: I opted for your stylesheet solution to control visibility, and it worked perfectly! I only had to remove the space between the '@' and '(' in front of showCompnent. Thank you very much. :)